# The value of the textarea isn't going into the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, web

```
if($_POST['button']){
    $name= $_POST['name'];
    $url= $_POST['url'];
    $description= $_POST['description'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO videos VALUES (
        '','$name','$url','$description'
        )");
}

echo '<h1>Add Video</h1>
<form action="addvideo.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
Url: <input type="text" name="url" /><br />
<a style="position:relative; top:-250px;">Description:</a> 
<textarea    name="description" style="height:500px; width:750px;"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="button" style="position:relative; top:-250px;" />
</form>';
```

This is my code for a website i am building where you can input data for a youtube video. It is then supposed to insert that in a table in my database. The problem is that when the description is in one line, it makes it break when it gets to the end of the textarea. This makes it not put anything into the table for some reason. So that is the question.

Comment: Try using mysql_real_escape_string on your assignments. ie. `$description= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);` or better yet use mysqli or pdo as mysql is now officially deprecated. It might also be useful to check the requrn of mysql_query and check it for errors.

Comment: What is the error you getting? What is the input of text area; just copy here!

Comment: This is another good example why you should use [prepared statement and variable binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @Orangepill Thanks that seemed to work. I also might try to look into using mysqli.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL_real_escape_string like

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $con = mysql_connect ('localhost','username','password') or die(mysql_error()); 
        mysql_select_db('database') or die(mysql_error());
    //$desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtDesc']);//nl2br($_POST['txtDesc']);
    $desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtDesc']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO desc_tbl (desc) VALUES('$desc')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
<form method="POST" action="textarea.php">
<textarea name="txtDesc" row = "50" cols = "50" id="txtDesc" wrap="hard"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `mysqli` over `mysql`. Also use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), they will save you from much trouble.